# How to set a value in WebView local storage before the view loads in React Native WebView

Tags: react-native, webview

I want to inject an access token in the webview before the web app is loaded. Basically, the web app will read the access token from the browser storage and use it to make calls to the secure API.

**The application flow is like this:**

1. User logs in to mobile app and gets the access token
2. The access token should then be set as a session storage property of a webview before the it starts loading
3. The web app reads the access token from the storage and makes calls to the API.

**What I have tried:**

1. onLoadStart - Works many times but still there is a race condition between view load and injection
2. injectJavaScript: Using this alongwith onLoadStart
3. injectedJavaScript: Doesn't work as the javascript is injected once the view starts loading

**Code:**

```
// Inject Access Token
_injectAccessToken = () => {
  const script = `window.sessionStorage.setItem("access_token", "token")`;
  this.webview.injectJavaScript(script);
};


// Render
<WebView
  ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}
  source={{ uri: `` }}
  onLoadStart={this._injectAccessToken}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
/>;
```

**What needs to be solved:**

Now I want to get rid of the race condition between view load and injection. I am not bound to using this solution, any other tricks or solutions will be fine as long as the injection will happen before view loads.

Any references or suggestions to other articles is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try componentWillMount ?

Comment: As I said, `componentWillMount` is called before the first render so the ref to webview will be undefined at that time

Comment: @Ajay any update? I am sort of stuck with same problem I want to achieve the same thing what you described above

Comment: @MuhammadZain I did solve this one but it was a long time ago. Give me till tomorrow and I'll answer this question myself. Thanks.

Comment: @Ajay will you please provide solution for this? Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadZain Added my answer. Hope you have already found a solution for this. If so, can you please share what was yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this and get the app in production.

Back then, I was using WebView which was provided with React Native itself. It wasn't working out so well, so had to switch to the new separated package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview

Using the below props on the WebView:

```
<WebView
  ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}
  source={{ uri: "SOME_URL" }}
  onLoadStart={() => this._injectAccessTokenOnLoad(params)}
  startInLoadingState
  useWebKit
  javaScriptEnabled
  domStorageEnabled
/>
```

Inject Access Token On Load Method:

```js
_injectAccessTokenOnLoad = (params) => {
  // Assuming that we are passing an object for "params"
  // No need to stringify if you are passing a string or a number
  const value = JSON.stringify(params);

  const script = `
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("SOME_KEY", '${value}');
    }, 100);
  `;
  
  this.webview.injectJavaScript(script);
};
```